# Determine $a$ such that $3x\cdot\cos x - ax = 0$ has () solutions...

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

An equation is given $3x\cdot\cos x - ax = 0$, for $x$ in $[0,2\pi]$. I am asked to determine $a$ such that the equation has two and three solutions. It seems that for only one solution $a$ is in the interval $a<-3$ and $a \geqslant 3$. I do not understand this, as I thought that the cosine function cannot go over $[-1,1]$. I reasoned that in that case, $a$ would be in $[-3,3]$. In what case would the equation have only one solution?

Answer (score 3):

$x=0$ will always be a solution.

Assuming $x\ne 0$ then we can say.

$3x\cos x = ax\\
\cos x = \frac {a}{3}$

If $a\in (-3,3)$ there will be two additional solutions.

$a = \pm 3$ there will be a solution at $x = \pi$ or $x = 2\pi$

Answer (score 2):

To answer `I do not understand this, as I thought that the cosine function cannot go over [-1,1]`. You are correct, the range of $\cos x$ is $[-1, 1]$. But in the given equation, $\cos x$ is being scaled by $3$ in the equation. For example, if $\cos x = 1$, then $3 \cos x = 3$. So $3 \cos x$ can take on any value in the closed interval $[-3, 3]$.

Comment: @Rodent McCoy; In what case would the equation have only one solution?

Comment: In the interval $[0, 2 \pi]$, the only case when the equation has one solution is when $a = -3$. Looking at $cos(x)$ on a graph, it reaches $cos(x) = 1$ at both $x = 0$ and $x = 2 \pi$. The reason why $a = -3$ is the only value of $a$ which gives one solution is because in its period, $cos(x) = \frac{a}{3} = \frac{-3}{3} =-1$ only is true in the interval $[0, 2 \pi]$ when $x = \pi$. Since cosine is periodic on intervals of $2 \pi$, we can see that this is also true when $x = - \pi$ and $x = 3 \pi$, but these solutions are not in the interval we are concerned with. Hopefully this helps.